# Dynamic system, fixed point

Tags: vector-spaces, dynamical-systems

Given the dynamic system $u^{k+1}=g(u^{k})$, and a vector $v ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies $v=g(v)$, which is said to be a fixed point of the system.

i) Suppose that the solution for a dynamic system converge, in other words, $\lim u^{k+1}=u^*$. Show that $u^*$ is a fixed point.

PS: Sorry for my English.

Comment: If $g$ is continuous, then it follows by continuity. Otherwise it is not true in general. If $u_0 = 1$ with $g(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}x & x > 0 \\ 1 & x \le 0 \end{cases}$, then $u_k \to 0$, but $0$ is not a fixed point.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\lim_{k \rightarrow +\infty} u^{k+1} = u^*$. By definition, This means that there exists a positive integer $M$ such that $u^k = u^*$ for all $k > M$. Suppose to take $k > M$ and consider that:

$$u^{k+1} = g(u^k)$$

We know that $u^k = u^*$ and also $u^{k+1}=u^*$, and hence $u^{k+1} = g(u^*) = u^*$. Then $u^*$ is a fixed point.

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot assume $u^k = u^*$ after some index.

Comment: You're right, there $u^*$ can be an asymptotically stable equilibrium and hence $u^k$ is near to $u^*$ with respect to a suitable norm.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g$ be a **continuous** function and $u^* = \lim u^{k+1}$.

Then $u^* = \lim u^{k+1} = \lim g(u^k) \underbrace{=}_{(*)} g (\lim u^k) = g(u^*)$. Therefore $u^*$ is a fixed point.

The equality $(*)$ holds only if $g$ is a continuous function.